# Flink Checkpoint completion time growing despite no new data being processed

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I have a job that has a few different states in it and have checkpointing configured to happen every 5 seconds. Now right now it is running at 50 parallelism with 1 cpu per task slot. For a quick test it is just consuming 60k records which it finishes in a matter of seconds. But I keep the job running for a few hours now because I noticed as it runs and continues to take checkpoints that the time for checkpoints to be completed goes from 4 seconds to 20 and so on until it hits its timeout.

I had the same job running over the weekend (checkpoint timeout for this one is 5 minutes). Started, processed all 45k records basically immediately, and the checkpoints were completing in 5 seconds or so. Then noticed that every 5th checkpoint exactly a checkpoint would take around 20 seconds to complete. Then the following 4 were all back to 5 seconds. Checked again today and each checkpoint is taking over a minute and a half to complete. Not seeing as consistent sudden time spikes but still see a couple take 1 minute 20 seconds, then two take 1 minute 35 seconds, then back to 1:20.

Here is the checkpoint configuration currently:

[image]

I am at a loss for why the checkpoint completion time keeps increasing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like Rocksdb settings have to be tuned. Alternatively, have you considered the possibility to migrate to HashMap state backend or your state size is too high to fit into memory? With this state backend, there will be no issues with checkpoint completion time.

Comment: Memory hasn't been an issue in the past when running with less parallelism and half as many task managers. The state went up to I think 20gb without issue before. I get the feeling its a network thing, but I even tried increasing network buffers to 10k and still had this issue (and the other one with slow startup from the other question I think you commented on as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this is that it was related to the infrastructure setup.

The tl;dr: RocksDB was on a shared volume that was over network.

So to break down a bit on exactly what was wrong (and credit for the in depth explanation goes to the infrastructure team member on the project) is the RocksDB was on a shared volume in the datacenter. And under the covers the provider uses NFS for shared volumes and NFS is not a great match for a workload with a high amount of transactions and IO such as that of the RocksDB.  Writes to an NFS volume require locks and multiple pods writing to the same NFS volume may run into contention between the pods requesting a lock.

So we moved away from using a PVC and instead switched to per-pod ephemeral storage using the emptyDir volume with a size limit so we don’t have to worry about a pod accidentally causing outages by filling up the underlying node.

And this is also fixed my other problem in this question, as it was basically a different symptom of the same issue ([Flink Job subtasks taking minutes to start, while source starts instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807059/flink-job-subtasks-taking-minutes-to-start-while-source-starts-instantly)).

Not sure if this should have more/different tags (or what those would be) since it wasn't exactly a flink issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some of what you are describing is normal, because rocksdb will sometimes perform compaction, which results in some checkpoints taking longer than others.

And even with no data being ingested or processed, timers could be causing state changes that require checkpointing.

Nevertheless, this sounds potentially worrisome. It would help to know what the job is doing, and whether you have enabled incremental checkpointing. And what about the checkpoint sizes -- do they plateau, or grow over time, or go up and down?

Can you share a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: It is ingesting from a kafka topic as the source, keying by a value and updating keyed value state and mapstate with a simple calculation, and updating the record that was passed through, then outputting it to a kafka topic sink. then keying by another value and updating a different valueState. So source -> keyBy -> vState1, mapState, and record update -> (output record to sink) -> keyBy -> update vState2. if that all makes sense. The checkpoint sizes are always the same. All checkpoints have a state of 2.52 MB. nothing new came in. processed 40k records within first 60 seconds and that was it

Comment: Sinks are terminal nodes in the DAG -- they can't have output. So I'm not sure how to interpret the second half of your pipeline: ... `-> (output record to sink) -> keyBy -> update vState2`.

Comment: yes incremental checkpoints. And yea, I couldnt think of a better way to display that. So it is: vState1, mapState, and record update(updateOperator1) has the output record to sink attached to it, but the next keyby is a direct map from updateOperator1. so without considering the the sink the flow is: source -> keyBy -> vState1, mapState, and record update -> keyBy -> update vState2. Sorry for the confusion on that