# Flink Job subtasks taking minutes to start, while source starts instantly

Tags: apache-flink

So I recently increased the parallelism of my flink job from 10 to 50. Currently the setup is 25 taskmanagers with 2 task slots each, each with 2 cpu. Job manager with 5 cpus. For some reason though, when the job starts, it is able to start up all the sub tasks for the two sources immediately, but the rest of the job takes a minute or more to start all the other operators' subtasks.
[image]

I know this shouldn't be happening, but I am not sure what needs to be changed to resolve this. Here is a screen shot of one of the task manager's configuration from the ui as well. Also it is checkpointing with rocksdb and using s3.

[image]

Comment: Does the subtasks have any heavy initialisation in open method ? Or any state broadcast ? What is the state size ? Thank you

Comment: The state right now never gets over 5MB. With the current setup there are about 40k records on the source topic and thats all it will process. One thing I didn't mention that I'll add is that I ran this job with parallelism of 10 (5 task managers with 2 slots each. 2 cpu each task manager) and with much higher volume (70 million records) of data and larger state size as a result (40gb or so) and it ran fine. average was about 155k records per second processed. Never had this issue until increasing to the 50 parallelism.

Comment: What is the deployment mode - yarn, k8s, etc ? are there actually slots available during this initialisation ? may it be the issue with allocating resources ? When I saw the same issue, sometimes it was just waiting for slots to be scheduled - could you please confirm the slots are available at the time of initialisation ?

Comment: Its k8s. and all resources are available from what I can tell. I watch the ui and the cluster starts up, all task managers and task slots show as available. Then the job starts. If there is a better way to verify than seeing the flink ui showing them as free before job starts, like a logging mode or something to look for in the tm or jm logs to verify its not waiting for resources, let me know and I can check with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this is that it was related to the infrastructure setup.

The tl;dr: RocksDB was on a shared volume that was over network.

So to break down a bit on exactly what was wrong (and credit for the in depth explanation goes to the infrastructure team member on the project) is the RocksDB was on a shared volume in the datacenter. And under the covers the provider uses NFS for shared volumes and NFS is not a great match for a workload with a high amount of transactions and IO such as that of the RocksDB.  Writes to an NFS volume require locks and multiple pods writing to the same NFS volume may run into contention between the pods requesting a lock.

So we moved away from using a PVC and instead switched to per-pod ephemeral storage using the emptyDir volume with a size limit so we don’t have to worry about a pod accidentally causing outages by filling up the underlying node.

And this is also fixed my other problem in this question, as it was basically a different symptom of the same issue ([Flink Checkpoint completion time growing despite no new data being processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806562/flink-checkpoint-completion-time-growing-despite-no-new-data-being-processed)).

Not sure if this should have more/different tags (or what those would be) since it wasn't exactly a flink issue.